# How to compile C mysql programs in Windows using minGW

Tags: mysql, c, windows, mingw

I'm attempting to compile a C program on Windows cmd with minGW but I keep getting the error message

```
 db_test.c:1:10: fatal error: my_global.h: No such file or directory
```

and I don't know how to fix the problem.

I installed minGW on my Windows 10 laptop and it works fine. (It can compile a simple Hello World program). Then I installed MySQL along with it's connectors (MySQL 8.0). Now I want to compile a MySQL program with it and I find it surprisingly difficult to compile it. I took the most basic code I could find in the internet and attempted compiling it. The code I ran was:

```
#include <my_global.h>
#include <mysql.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  printf("MySQL client version: %s\n", mysql_get_client_info());

  exit(0);
}
```

The compile line I used was:

```
gcc -o db_test db_test.c -I"C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\include" -L"C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\lib\libmysql" -lmysqlclient
```

This I took from several sources. But I keep getting that error message. 
I couldn't find any resources to get over this problem. Most of the internet resources are for Linux users.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Where is `my_global.h` supposed to live? Are you sure it's in one of the include paths you've specified?

Comment: @tadman Thank you! I'm sorry I've been foolish not to think of this. I did a complete search in my system for my_global.h and found no hits. Maybe I should find another example.

Comment: I'd check [the documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/c-api.html) for more up-to-date examples. 8.0 reorganized a lot of things that may have broken older code.